# HAML substitute collection select

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, html-select

I have a form with a collection select for buildings:

```
f.collection_select :build, @builds, :build_a, :build_b
```

And I want to attach a `data-country` attribute to the generated option tags with data from @builds[:country] so I can hide or show them with javascript depending on other form field.

How I can achieve this in HAML?

Answer (score 0):

You could write in HAML what the `collection_select` does and check if the HTML generated will suit your needs:

```
%select{name:'build'}
  - @builds.each do |build|
    %option{value: build.id, data: { country: @builds[:country] }}
      = build.name
```